# Ruby and Bonjour

Tags: ruby, bonjour, tcpserver, dns-sd

I am new to ruby and its library, but how do i combine DNSSD and TCPServer together?

I know i can register DNSSD service via

```
registration = DNSSD.register("My Files", hostname, "local.", port)
```

And I can create a DNSSD service for my TCPServer this way, but how do i specify the hostname (service name) as the above?

```
server = TCPServer.open(port)
DNSSD.announce server, 'my awesome HTTP server'
```

I want to broadcast my server, so that the client can resolve the DNSSD service and establish a connection.

Pardon me if thats a stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to setup it up via

1. Register a DNSSD aka Bonjour Service

> ```
> DNSSD.register("", hostname, "local.", port) do |register_reply|
> puts "Registration result: #{register_reply.inspect}"
> end
> ```

2. Setup TCPServer to listen on the same port

> ```
> blackjack = TCPServer.open("",port)
> loop do
> socket = blackjack.accept
> peeraddr = socket.peeraddr
> puts "Connection from %s:%d" % socket.peeraddr.values_at(2, 1)
> end
> ```